# How to use finally in HttpClient Angular 7

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-http, angular-httpclient, finally

In the previous versions of Angular, I use `finally()` just fine like the code below

```
constructor(
    private http: Http
) { }

const headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': this.authenticate.getToken(), 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.put(Globals.SERVER_URL + '/alert/exempted?_id=' + alertId + '&isExempted=' + status + '&app_id=' + app_id, options )
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError)
                .finally(() => {
                    this.exceptionSubject.next();
});
```

But now when with Angular 7, I can't use it anymore. How to insert finally in the code (HttpClient)? Here is my existing code:

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
) { }

const header = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); 
return this.http.get(Globals.ATTENDANCE_URL + '/individual_employment_setting/detail/' + id, { headers: header })
        .pipe(tap(resp => {
            if (resp['success'] === true) {
                localStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(resp['data']));
            }
        }
));
```

Comment: .pipe(finalize(() => {





      }))